# modifying bartik

Tags: theming

I'm in progress of designing a new theme based on the `Bartik responsive` theme. Now I would like to move my navigation all the way in the top left corner but I can't get it there, I don't find the property that keeps it centered. Can anyone help? My design so far looks like: http://www.spabc.com/drupal/ I'm still in the very early process of building the theme.

Comment: Questions about CSS are off topic here, you may be able to get help with this on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its easy, for `#header` set

```
#header{
    display : inline-block;
    width : 100%;
}
```

and for the `DIV` below it,

```
#header > div:first-child{
    float : left;
}
```

or

```
#header > div:nth-child(1){
    float : left;
}
```

it is the result

[image]